# Updating the DataGridView cells and going to another form to show updates

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, updating

I made a DataGridView with UI. The goal is redirecting the current form including the DataGridView table to another form to show the table updates after any changes in cells. Actually I didn't write any codes and just used the interface. I used a lot of events such as CellValueChanged but they didn't work. so that they show several new irrelevant forms when the event control fires. This code  however had a better functionality

```js
        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            new Form_result().Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

The problem is when I use this code it goes to another form but doesn't perform the cell changes. Could I ask you to help me please by solving this problem or suggesting another method

Comment: How do you use `DataGridView` in another form? What makes you think what cells are not changed? Typically there is underlying data which is displayed in both forms and maybe editing `DataGridView` doesn't changes that data (which makes you think cells are not changed).

Comment: [`CellEndMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx) *occurs when edit mode stops for the currently selected cell*. Data are not yet commited. You have to use another event, [`CellValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good candidate, because it *occurs when the user-specified value is committed, which typically occurs when focus leaves the cell.* Why and how exactly it wasn't working when you tried it?

Comment: Many thanks for the response. The problem was related to the DB. Now it has been solved.